# How to catch thrown error from require using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, import, try-catch, option-type, require

I am trying to use [optional module loading in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios) for the [webextension-polyfill-ts](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill-ts) module.

I need to do so because I am building a library, using TypeScript, which must work on nodejs, browser and browser extension.

Unfortunately, underlying Mozilla's [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) is throwing an error in non-WebExtension contexts.

Using TypeScript's optional loading, it throw an error, even if it should not load the module in the context.

Using try-catch block, I can't catch the error.

Here are samples:

Using optional loading

```js
import * as Browser from "webextension-polyfill-ts";
let browser: any = false;

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
if (typeof chrome !== "undefined" && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.id) {
  browser = require("webextension-polyfill-ts");
} else {
  console.log("a");
}

export default browser;
```

Using try-catch

```js
let browser: any = null;

try {
  browser = require("webextension-polyfill-ts");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("a");
}

export default browser;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it didn't work. It was bound to [tinyify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyify). Simply removing its usage with browserify fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you cannot catch the error, but maybe try typescript import?
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/dynamic-import-expressions-in-typescript

Looks like it returns a promise that you could catch.

```
import("./widget").then(widget => {
  widget.render(container);
}).catch((err) => { console.log('error', err) });
```

Comment: Hi. I tried what you asked.
I should precise I am testing in the browser with browserify and tsify. Maybe it's bound to the way they transform the code.

Here is the code I used:

```let browser: any = false;

import("webextension-polyfill-ts")
  .then((Browser) => {
    browser = Browser;
  })
  .catch((e) => {});

export default browser;
```

Comment: This might not be a great fit since export is synchronous. You could try exporting the promise.

Comment: Oh! You're right, I didn't think about it.

But anyway, it does not change the result.

```export const browser: any = import("webextension-polyfill-ts")
  .then((browser) => browser)
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("a");
    return false;
  });
```

still throw the error, without being catched.